# Convert decimal to byte array

Tags: c#, .net

assume I have `decimal X`

I want to calculate 3 byte as `a,b,c` where `a.bc` Gig is near X.

I want it to be clean and as short as it possible.

I've already implement it but it is very bad but works.

for example `X = 2972117368`, I want `a = 2, b = 7, c = 6` . how?

2972117368/(1024*1024*1024) = 2.76799999922514

X will be always lesser than 9.99 gigabyte.

Comment: please be more specific and give more examples.

Comment: basically, you have a number of bytes, and need the number of gigabytes, rounded off to two decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((double.Parse((X / (1024.0 * 1024 * 1024)).ToString("0.00")) * 100).ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Is seems like you're most of the way there:

```
decimal x = 2972117368;
double gig = Convert.ToDouble(x) / 1073741824.0;

byte a = (byte)Math.Floor(gig); // works for up to 127 gig - actually up to 256
byte b = (byte)(Math.Floor(gig * 10) % 10);
byte c = (byte)(Math.Floor(gig * 100) % 10);
```

Edited: For some typos & logical errors

Comment: well, it doesn't correspond to OP's example: X = 2972117368, I want a = 2, b = 7, c = 6

Comment: Yeah, I'd not tried it - there were a couple of howlers! Should work now.

Comment: Yes! I though the signed-ness would knacker it! Forgot that byte is unsigned.